# Kestrel on AspNet vNext doesnt serve index page under /

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I need to be able to serve my 'index.html', under the default url */*, using Kestrel web server. Right now I'm only able to access my static files with the full path i.e */index.html*

Again this works perfectly on VisualStudio, the context is OSX with Kestrel

This is my *Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(DI.IServiceCollection services)
 {   
     services.AddMvc();
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
 {
     app.UseStaticFiles();
     app.UseMvc();
 }
```

The solution I have so far, is to do a redirect inside a HomeController. But this is plain ugly, I'm trying to serve an static html file, which I honestly don't want it to be handled by my Application, if possible served directly from Kestrel.

Comment: Can you post a capture of your project?.It seems like you are not foolowing the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to enable the `DefaultFilesMiddleware` using `UseDefaultFiles()` and place it **before** the call to `UseStaticFiles()`:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

If you don't specify otherwise, the middleware uses the `DefaultFilesOptions` by default, which means this list of default file names will be used:

```
default.htm
default.html
index.htm
index.html
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.defaultfilesextensions.usedefaultfiles%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: This is a good answer, I marked it solved, although it still doesnt do it for me. The empty / url is still not serving. I'm still thinking it may be related to the Kestrel Server somehow.

Comment: Try to call `UseDefaultFiles()` *before* `UseStaticFiles()`. Also, see https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/issues/10

Comment: you totally got it!, I will suggest the previous comment as part of the answer

Comment: One thing I was completely missing is that the _html_ file has to reside in a **folder** named wwwroot, it may not be placed in the project root as previously in ASP.NET, if it might help anyone :)