# Asp.net core 1.1 material Design Icons

Tags: asp.net-core, material-design, materialize, asp.net-core-1.1

I'm trying to use [Material Design Icons](http://materializecss.com/) in my project. I'm able to make a page successfully, but when I add icons to the page using `i` tags as described in [`materializecss` documentation](http://materializecss.com/icons.html) their class have the default path i.e. in `font/material-design-icons/allFOntsfileshere`. The problem is that when I add these my browser keeps saying "restricted access".

```
<div class="row margin">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="mdi-social-person-outline prefix"></i>
        <input id="MobileNumber" type="text">
        <label for="MobileNumber" class="center-align indigo-text darken-2">
            Mobile Number
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could give a bit more context (eg. how are you configuring your middleware). But since I stumbled upon a similar problem I think I might guess what's he issue you're having.

You probably haven't configured `static files` middleware.
You should check Microsoft's documentation article on [Working with static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files), but here's what you should do to fix it in case the url changes:

First you need to set your `ContentRoot` in your `Program.cs`

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) //Like this
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

> In order for static files to be served, you must configure the Middleware to add static files to the pipeline. The static file middleware can be configured by adding a dependency on the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/) package to your project and then calling the `UseStaticFiles` extension method from `Startup.Configure`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    /*...*/
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    /*...*/
}
```

You need to consider that the order in which you add your middleware matters. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30232621/2226079) answer that specifies the required order between `UseStaticFiles` and `UseDefaultFiles`.